# UWP Release build error - Missing assembly and XmlSerializer implicit conversion errors

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a app that uses the XmlSerializer to serialize a list of UWP's `BasicGeoposition` to a file. 
When building for `Debug` on X86/64 and ARM everything works fine, but when switching to the `Release` build scheme to build it with .NET Native, the compiler throws the following errors:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0012: The type 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [{...}\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [{...}\oobj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [{...}\oobj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [{...}\oobj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]'
```

The stack trace:

```
at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence, String outputDir, IEnumerable`1 referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, Boolean loadAssembly)
at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Hashtable assemblies, String outputDir, IEnumerable`1 referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, Boolean loadAssembly)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer(Type[] types, XmlMapping[] mappings, CompilerParameters parameters, String outputDir, IEnumerable`1 referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, Boolean loadAssembly)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer(Type[] types, String outputDir, IEnumerable`1 referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, List`1 wcfSerializers, Boolean loadAssembly)
at SerializationAssemblyGenerator.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Why does this happen? How to resolve this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 CE.

**EDIT: I've narrowed it down to `XmlSerializer`. When I comment out any XmlSerializer stuff in my code everything builds fine with the `Release` configuration.**

Full compiler output:

```
Restoring NuGet packages...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
1>------ Build started: Project: Racepad2, Configuration: Release x86 ------
1>C:\Users\gala\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\src\Racepad2\Core\Navigation\Parsers.cs(111,46,111,47): warning CS0168: The variable 'e' is declared but never used
1>  Racepad2 -> C:\Users\gala\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\bin\x86\Release\Racepad2.exe
1>  Starting .NET Native compilation
1>  Processing application code
1>  Computing application closure and generating interop code
1>  Generating serialization code
1>  Compiling interop code
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : error CS0012: The type 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition' to 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd]'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition' to 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd]'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition> [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\System.Collections.dll]'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd]' to 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition [c:\Users\gala\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Racepad2\Racepad2\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd]' to 'Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error :    at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence, String outputDir, IEnumerable`1 referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, Boolean loadAssembly)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error :    at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Hashtable assemblies, String outputDir, IEnumerable`1 referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, Boolean loadAssembly)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error :    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer(Type[] types, XmlMapping[] mappings, CompilerParameters parameters, String outputDir, IEnumerable`1 referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, Boolean loadAssembly)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error :    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer(Type[] types, String outputDir, IEnumerable`1 referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir, List`1 wcfSerializers, Boolean loadAssembly)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error :    at SerializationAssemblyGenerator.Program.Main(String[] args)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\.Net\.NetNative\15.0.24211\x86\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : Internal compiler error: One or more errors occurred.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: What's your `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` version number?

Comment: How can I check that? Sorry I'm new to the Microsoft ecosystem.

Comment: I see you figured it out. ;)

Comment: Yeah, stuff was outdated. How I did not notice this started when I updated Visual Studio, I really don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst looking how to use NuGet to replace XmlSerializer with a JSON solution, I stumbled upon the updates section. Turns out the NETCore .NET Native runtime was outdated, version 5.2.4. Updating to version 5.4.0 solved the issue.